# Selenium IDE vs Webdriver performance, how can I improve this?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

I have built some functional tests in Selenium IDE with the aim of exporting these to run either in JUnit or similar. Running these tests inside the IDE was quite impressive, the tests I ran took around 4 seconds a test. However I have since exported these tests and run them in JUnit, and the tests are all of a sudden taking 12-14 seconds to perform. Even using a headless webdriver we are still looking at 10 second tests.

I have run IDE linked through webdrivers to open up other browsers and they still run much faster than through the WebDriver from JUnit.

Does anyone have any advice on improving the Webdriver performance so that I don't have to run everything from Firefox.

Comment: it'll help to see some code.  i've never seen this behavior before

Comment: ide is pure javascript, but webdriver calls made by programming languages so it is a normal behavour. because, each language has their processes to start/progress. so, starting and ending of testcase can take a little more time. important point is your test steps

Comment: We're not talking about starting test cases, it's just consistently across the board with all steps. IDE takes for example 0.2s to verify text, PhantomJS using JUnit takes 0.6s and RC using the HTML generated in IDE takes 1.3s